# django admin change page add foreign key error: server refuses to connect

Tags: django, django-admin, django-deployment

I have a model called "press" with a field for "lab", which is another model. on the admin change page for an object in "press", I can choose the "lab" from a list, or click the green plus sign to add a new one. In development, this works fine.

the choice box:
[image]

after clicking the 'add' sign IN DEVELOPMENT
[image]

looks good. BUT, on my actual site, this is what happens. the red is the name of the server/root url of the site
[image]

This is not the only time this happens. It is every 'plus' button that adds a new item to a foreign key field.

the link on the button in this case was
dev: http://.../admin/press/lab/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1
actual: https://.../admin/press/lab/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1

everything there looks ok.

ALSO on the actual site, if i click 'add' on the left menu, it works fine.
[image]

in that case, the link is: https://.../admin/press/lab/add/

is the problem because the first case is a popup? or it doesn't like /?_to_field=id
any ideas?

EDIT. i think it's an x-frame options issue. Mine is set to "DENY" in settings.py, because that was advised for keeping things secure. Changing it to "SAMEORIGIN" fixed everything. But, that seems to go against the recommended usage. is there a way to keep things secure and still have the functionality?

Comment: You have some configuration issue such that any links to other places go to https which isn't available.  You need to make sure that there are no https links (aside for non-local ones)

Comment: but, https is available. i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Either https or http isn't available; but that's only a guess.  Without actual configuration code, it's difficult to figure out the issue.

Comment: I found that the problem goes away when I change x-frame-options from 'deny' to 'sameorigin' in settings.py. but, 'deny' is the recommended settings. it's confusing to me.

Comment: I'm glad you got that solved; but the issue is in order to get help, you need to provide a bit more information other than screenshots; normally that'd entail including django configuration code.